# Postgres tsvector_update_trigger sometimes takes minutes

Tags: performance, postgresql, tsvector

I have configured free text search on a table in my postgres database. Pretty simple stuff, with firstname, lastname and email. This works well and is fast.

I do however sometimes experience looong delays when inserting a new entry into the table, where the insert keeps running for minutes and also generates huge WAL files. (We use the WAL files for replication).

Is there anything I need to be aware of with my free text index? Like Postgres maybe randomly restructuring it for performance reasons? My index is currently around 400 MB big.

Thanks in advance!

Christian

Answer (score 1):

Given the size of the WAL files, I suspect you are right that it is an index update/rebalancing that is causing the issue.  However I have to wonder what else is going on.

I would recommend against storing tsvectors in separate columns.  A better way is to run an index on to_tsvector()'s output.  You can have multiple indexes for multiple languages if you need.  So instead of a trigger that takes, say, a field called description and stores the tsvector in desc_tsvector, I would recommend just doing:

```
 CREATE INDEX mytable_description_tsvector_idx ON mytable(to_tsvector(description));
```

Now, if you need a consistent search interface across a whole table, there are more elegant ways of doing this using "table methods."

In general the functional index approach has fewer issues associated with it than anything else.

Now a second thing you should be aware of are partial indexes.  If you need to, you can index only records of interest.  For example, if most of my queries only check the last year, I can:

```
 CREATE INDEX mytable_description_tsvector_idx ON mytable(to_tsvector(description))
  WHERE created_at > now() - '1 year'::interval;
```